# Import Local Meteor MongoDB to DigitalOcean Ubuntu server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

Following other stackoverflow posts, I'm able to export my local database into my app folder (located at dump/meteor).

Then, I've re-deployed, using mup, to my server. No problems there.

I then log onto my server, enter the mongo shell, and dump the old database (called tapshop) using db.dropDatabase(). `show dbs` confirmed it's present but empty.

Then, after exiting the mongo shell, I try `mongorestore --db tapshop dump/meteor` and get the following message:

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1
don't know what to do with file [dump/meteor]
```

I know I'm missing something in that mongorestore command, but what?

Answer (score 0):

here is the syntax I use

```
mongorestore --host localhost --drop  --dir ${backup_fullpath}
```

which destroys current mongo and replaces with all db from backup dir

Comment: Is it possible to use a local path for ${backup_fullpath}? I think the problem is that the dump folder isn't being uploaded to my server with mup.

Comment: Can you post the result of 'ls -la dump/meteor' on the server? It should be a folder with .bson and .json files.

Comment: Using the proper path on my local machine gives just that, a list of bson and json files (this is probably going to look ugly): 
Bryces-MacBook-Pro:~ brycekirk$ ls -la /Users/brycekirk/Documents/Websites/tapshop/dump/meteor
total 88
drwxr-xr-x  20 brycekirk  staff   680  3 May 16:13 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 brycekirk  staff   102  3 May 16:13 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 brycekirk  staff     0  3 May 16:13 __pre_profileImg.bson
-rw-r--r--   1 brycekirk  staff   222  3 May 16:13 __pre_profileImg.metadata.json 
etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the **port** option in the command line:

```
mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --drop --db tapshop dump/meteor
```

Remember, in development, mongo runs on port 3001, but in production runs on port 27017.

Comment: Using that command I still get the error "connected to: 127.0.0.1:27017
don't know what to do with file [dump/meteor]"

Answer (score 0):

After endless googling I was able to do it. Not the most efficient route, but hey, it works.

First, I added my local dump folder to my server:

```
scp -r PATH_TO_DUMP_FOLDER USER@SERVER:PATH_TO_SAVE_FOLDER
```

Then I just ran the mongorestore command after logging into my server:

```
mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --drop --db DB_NAME PATH_TO_DUMP_FOLDER
```